# Apply style to search results

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016

I'm trying to use the Search/Replace function to find all occurrences of a string in a paragraph, then apply one of my defined styles to all results.

Have tried the following:

- ctrl-F to bring up search dialog, and enter string to search for
- Select Replace to bring up Replace dialog box
- In Replace dialog, select Format->Style, then choose the style I want.  The selected style shows up under the Replace with: input field.
- Click on Find Next, then Replace

The application of the style always applies to the entire paragraph, and not just to the search result.

Is this a bug, or am I omitting a step?

Comment: What's the style that you're trying to apply? Are you sure that it's defined as a character style rather than a paragraph style? If it's a paragraph style, it will be applied to the whole paragraph where the string occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to depend on the style you're replacing with. For example, if I use this format:

[image]

...the entire paragraph switches to Heading 1 style, but if I use this format:

[image]

...only the word is switched to Heading 1 style. That's because the first one uses a *paragraph*-level style, and the second uses a character style.

Take a look at the styles you're using. The easiest way to check is to right-click on the style and choose "Modify". If the Style Type is "Paragraph", then it will be applied to whole paragraph. You want one with Style Type "Character".

Comment: Wow.  Safe to say I wouldn't have figured that out.  (I'm a bit new to styles).

The style in question is user-defined, and called Code.  And curiously, it's Style Type is 'Linked (paragraph and character)'.  Not even sure what that means, probably because I didn't know what I was doing (entirely) when I defined it.

But you've led me to my answer.  When I choose a style to replace with from the Replace dialog, in the box that comes up, my style (Code) is present.  But there is an option 'Code Char' as well.  If I choose that, all is well.

Thanks!